# CakePHP - Undefined Property when trying $this->Restaurant->City->find('list');

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to allow an admin to edit "restaurants" - one of the things they need to be able to change is the city where the restaurant is located.  So - I'm trying to pass the list of cities in my "cities" table to my /restaurants/admin_edit.ctp via the restaurants_controller.php

```
function admin_edit($id = null) {
    $this->set('cities', $this->Restaurant->City->find(
        'list', array('order' => 'City.name', 'fields' => 'City.id, City.name')));

        ...etc
```

I hope / assume this is a stupid issue and something I'm just doing wrong since I'm new to CakePHP, but after an hour and a half searching, I cannot find an explanation of how I can get the list of cities from the restaurants_controller.php

I have set up my hasOne in the restaurant.php model, and my belongsToMany in my city.php model (not sure if that matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So - the issue was, my associations were off.  I missunderstood the associations, but after reading [this incredibly helpful article](http://jbenner.net/blog/understanding-cakephp-associations), I rewrote my associations (hasMany, belongsTo...etc), and voila - the "find" worked perfectly.

I also found a few places that said I could use a $uses variable, but I found a few other places that dismissed that immediately, and said to just use correct associations.

Comment: Yup, generally `$uses` is not needed if you have your associations correct. If you find yourself using `$uses` a lot, it might be time to rethink your DB design

Comment: I thought so, but always glad to hear someone else verify :)  Thanks.